# Custom input option for a "select" parameter

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

Is it possible to have a "select" parameter with pre-defined options, that also accepts random manual input by the user? So the user can enter "air" into the example below.

```
 {
  "name":"a",
  "label":"A",
  "type":"select",
  "options": [
    {
      "value": "apple"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable validation of the value using `"validate": false` like in the example below. Then it is possible to switch the select field to the mapping mode and enter an arbitrary value.

```json
{
  "name":"a",
  "label":"A",
  "type":"select",
  "validate": false,
  "options": [
    {
      "value": "apple"
    }
  ]
}
```

More info here: https://docs.integromat.com/apps/other/parameters/select#validate